# how to search a value from database table and display result to web site in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

Iam trying to search a value from database table and display result to web site using laravel.
blade.php code is

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{URL::Route('postSearch')}}">
<div class="form-group {{($errors->has('pname'))?'has-error':''}}">
<label for="pname">Name :</label><input id="pname" name="pname" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default"></div>
</form>
```

my controller.php is here `else
         {   // $parents=Input::get('pname');
              $parents=new ForumParent();
              $parents->pname=Input::get('pname');
              var_dump(Input::get('pname'));
             if($parents)
             {
              return Redirect::route('view',$parents->pname);
             }
            else
             {
                return Redirect::route('getSearch')
                ->with('fail','value not found,please try again');
             }
       }`
this is my code..i want when we enter a name to the textbox ,is it in the database table ,or not.if is yes display details from the table (only display address)otherwise 404 error. how to check it.?

how to solve ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\view.blade.php)

Comment: my view.blade.php is  

    @foreach($parents as $parent)
{{$parent->pmobile}}
 {{$parent->paddress}}
<input type="hidden" name="pname" id="pname" value="{{$parent->pname}}">

Answer (score 0):

You have ForumParent model. So first search with  pname if get the result return the address or 404 otherwise.
In your postSearch action will be like this for else part

```
else{
   try {
        $pname = Input::get('pname');
        $parents = ForumParent::where('pname', $pname)->first();           

        if(empty($parents))
        {
            throw new  \Exception("Parent not found");              
        }           
        return Redirect::route('view',$parents->address);       

    } catch (Exception $e) {            
        abort(404);
    }
 }
```

The view action will be like this. Imagine parent_view.blade.php to show the address of parent.

```
public function view($address)
{
    return View::make('parent_view', compact('address'));
}
```

Comment: thank ...but one error occur...
InvalidArgumentExceptionView [view] not found.
 my route.php  is.     Route::group(array('prefix' =>'/search'),function()
{
  Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@getSearch','as'=>'getSearch'));
  Route::post('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@postSearch','as'=>'postSearch'));
  Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'),function()
   {Route::get('/view/{paddress}',array('uses'=>'SearchController@view','as'=>'view'));
  });}); .

Comment: my controller.php view code is...........public function view($paddress)
    {  
       return View::make('view', compact('paddress'));
    }                                                                                                                      view .blade.php is ......@foreach($paddress as $padd)
Adress:{{$padd->paddress}}
@endforeach.....                                                                                            i got answer in URL ..but not in web page...http://localhost/lara3/lara3/public/search/view/asdfgh%20jklzxcvbn%20mrettyyt%20rut what is wrong????

Comment: paddress is my address name in table(ForumParent)

Comment: how to write routes.php??

Comment: Please clarify your controller, model and routes file. As well as database structure of parent and parent address

Comment: my routes.php is.....                                                                                      Route::group(array('prefix' =>'/search'),function()
{
  Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@getSearch','as'=>'getSearch'));
  Route::post('/', array('uses'=>'SearchController@postSearch','as'=>'postSearch'));
 
  Route::group(array('before' =>'auth'),function()
 {
   Route::get('/search/viewsearch/{pname}',array('uses'=>'SearchController@viewsearch','as'=>'viewsearch'));
  });
});

Comment: Controller.php is same as your code only one differenec is addresss not ' paddress'
  public function viewsearch($paddress)
    {  
       $parents=ForumParent::find($paddress);
       //$users=User::all();
       return View::make('search.viewsearch')
       ->with('parents',$parents);
       //->with('users',$users);
    }                                my viewsearch.blade.php is here...@foreach($parents as $parent)
 {{$parent->pmobile}} {{$parent->paddress}}
     <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$parent->id}}">

Comment: now my problem is.. this 
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara3\lara3\app\views\search\viewsearch.blade.php)
can u check my routes.php is right or not .but i got answer in URL like this   http://localhost/lara3/lara3/public/search/search/viewsearch/ammufhgfhgf%20hfg bt not in web page..error occur..srry my bad english